# How to get menu items command CanExecute to apply when using images and text

Tags: wpf, xaml, menuitem

If I convert my menu code from:

```
<MenuItem Header="Remove Special Event" 
          Command="{Binding RemoveSpecialEventCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

To:

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding RemoveSpecialEventCommand, Mode=OneWay}">
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="Images/RemoveSpecialEvent.png" Stretch="None" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
            <TextBlock>Remove Special Event</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

Now the `Command` `CanExecute` is not being applied to the menu item. They are all enabled.

### Update

> I don't particularly expect this to work.

It worked!

[image: Menu]

Comment: Are they *enabled* enabled, or do they just *look* enabled?

Comment: Can you put the image in MenuItem.Icon instead, and use a plain string for Header the way you did before? `<MenuItem Header="Remove Special Event" Command="{Binding ...}"><MenuItem.Icon><Image Source="..." /></MenuItem.Icon></MenuItem>`

Comment: @EdPlunkett I can't use the `MenuItem.Icon` approach as I need that column for a check box. But in answer to your first question, they just *look* enabled.

Comment: This isn't something silly like just need to add IsHitTestVisible=True or ClickMode=Press to the object is it? At first glance it seems like it should be fine without investigating further.

Comment: @ChrisW. I don't know. I have not used those properties before. Where would they go?

Comment: For me, your menu item XAML displays with grayed-out text when I explicitly set `IsEnabled="False"` on the `MenuItem` element. Are you certain that it really is disabled when you think it is, and that the `CanExecuteChanged` event on that command is being raised when it should be?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Just put breakpoint in. It does get intercepted. If I use the `MenuItem.Icon` approach, perhaps I can come up with a equivalent icon for "checked". But my command it being executed. The item is getting disabled (because I can't select it). But it does not look disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue, and I'm going to take you at your word that it's absolutely disabled, but yet does not gray out the text. I suppose it might be a theme thing.

Here's one thing you can try: Instead of giving the `Header` property a visual tree fragment, try templating the plain string header content instead.

```
<MenuItem
    Header="Remove Special Event"
    Command="{Binding RemoveSpecialEventCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
    >
    <MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image 
                    Source="Images/RemoveSpecialEvent.png" 
                    Stretch="None" 
                    Margin="0,0,5,0"
                    />
                <ContentControl 
                    Content="{Binding}" 
                    />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

I don't particularly expect this to work.

Comment: That actually worked! I edited your answer with the screen shot. Feel free to remove it. I appreciate that normally the images should go in the left edge but then I had the image with the requirement of the check box for the last menu item. Otherwise I would have used your `MenuItem.Icon` approach.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle That's good news! If you need both the checkmark and the image, you need both, and it looks great the way you've got it. The beauty of WPF is it lets you stuff anything you need to in there. I'd put the screenshot in your question, seems more appropriate there.